# problems in accessing reservoir engineering data using Ocean API

Tags: ocean, petrel

I am building a plug in where I need to access the Reservoir engineering domain data using ocean API. I can access the development strategy using Simulation root but not been able to get the type of development strategy. Whether its history strategy or Prediction strategy.
Any way to know this information.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no Ocean API to access the type of the development strategy.  I will add your use case to our requirement system.

Regards,
Carole

Answer (score 1):

Having faced multiple limitations in Petrel RE API, and having to go through EclipseKeywordEditor a lot to achieve the goal, I have to say this is an easy one. DevelopmentStrategy.StrategyType property is there to help:

The following code is working for me on Petrel 2012.1:

```cs
SimulationRoot sroot = SimulationRoot.Get(PetrelProject.PrimaryProject);
DevelopmentStrategyCollection dsCol = DevelopmentStrategyCollection.NullObject;
if (sroot.HasDevelopmentStrategyCollection)
{
    dsCol = sroot.DevelopmentStrategyCollection;
    foreach (DevelopmentStrategy strat in dsCol.DevelopmentStrategies)
    {
        PetrelLogger.InfoOutputWindow(string.Format("{0} is a {1} strat",strat.Name,strat.StrategyType));
    }
}
```

DevGuide doesn't list it, IntelliSense doesn't show it, yet you can bring up Object Browser and see it's actually there (grayed out in fact).